# Is there a general rule for windows drivers as to which can have filter drivers?

Tags: windows-10, display-driver

Specifically I would like to know if for WDDM if the windows provided display port driver/display mini port driver can have a filter driver between them? I have read on an OSR forum that the old (XPDM) windows provided video port driver and hardware provided video miniport driver interface was not filterable and I am wonder why? And if this is so in the analogous interface in WDDM?

Comment: Unless you provide us what you read, it's difficult to answer your question, because we have to assume what you read was even correct

Comment: I can try to find the link however there is no casual way to conclude it's validity from it. It was an OSR blog. To me it seems there is no reason to suggest it wouldn't be filterable? I really need someone who can explain why it is or isn't. It is the video driver architecture which I know is a little bit different from standard device driver.

Comment: You indicated by your tags you are using Windows 10.  You then indicated that an <sic> *old* XDDM driver wasn't filterable.  So in order to determine if what you read applies to WDDM, I have to read, what you read.  The WDDM has changed **significiantly** even between Windows Version 1511 and Windows 10 Version 1607.  XDDM was Windows 2000 which is ancient, one should assume, nothing about XDDM is appliciable to the current version of WDDM until it is.

Comment: As to the actual reason the XDDM driver was not filterable, it was a design decision that Microsoft made, please provide the require clarification to your question so it can be answered.

Comment: The link giving no reason as to why it wasn't filterable, perhaps it wasn't WDF supplied filter, but maybe is for KMDF. https://www.osronline.com/ShowThread.cfm?link=173224

Comment: I see references to `XPDM` not `XDDM` in that thread.

Comment: The OSR forum is a professional resource for Windows drivers Asking here hardly would bring you better answers.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: I can find no evidence that WDDM has received any changes with regards to allowing filtered driver compared to XPDM.  In other words WDDM has remained unchanged in this regard.  My research is based on another thread on that same link, which asked a similar question, which had a more detailed response.  I just don't have the link, for whatever reason, its not in my history.

Comment: They have essentially changed the names from video port to display port but is still a driver/mini port driver pair. The interface has changed quite a bit as far as actual functionality. I have to assume it is possible using the lower more verbose and technical KMDF instead of WDF (which removes boiler plate code for you, for instance any interface which isn't registered by your driver entry function is automatically passed down to the next driver object). I could write my miniport driver and load the vender supplied miniport driver as a child driver object. Then call it's driver entry.

Comment: And pass my interface to it's.